# Foreach in foreach calling knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I was trying to find on similar posts solution, but mine attempts dont work.

**Idea:**
Simply I have Services and ServiceTypes. I packed it in my MVC controller method like this:

```
public class SimpleGroupedService
{
    public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceTypeName { get; set; }
    public List<SimpleServiceDTO> GroupedServices { get; set; }
}
```

Im passing to my js the whole object as `services`. So the object `services` contains also `GroupedServices` object which is a list.

[image: object services]

**Problem:**
In my html I'm trying foreach within foreach loop, and first level of services is ok, it shows serviceTypeName correctly, however, second foreach is broken.

```
<section class="list-container">
    <div>
        <!-- ko foreach: services -->
        <header>
            <i class="icon-employee"></i>
            <span data-bind="text: $root.shell.substring(ServiceTypeName, 200)"></span>
        </header>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" data-bind="text: $root.GroupedServices"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</section>
```

**Error shown:**
I dont have any errors in my console log unless I put something like this `data-bind="text: $root.GroupedServices.Name"`

then I have an error:

```
knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:63 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return $parent.GroupedServices.Name }"
Message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')
    at text (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:59), <anonymous>:3:88)
    at update (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:88)
    at a.j.o (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:63)
    at k (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:42)
    at Object.a.s.a.j (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:45)
    at knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:63
    at Object.u (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:10)
    at f (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:62)
    at h (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:60)
    at g (knockout-3.2.0.js?v=1.7.2:60)
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but GroupedServices is an array of objects so wouldn't you access it like `$root.GroupedServices[0].Name` or `$root.GroupedServices()[0].Name` if it was a knockout observableArray

Comment: As Nathan notes, your data structure is not what you think. Add `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(services, null, 2)"></pre>` in front of your `<section>`, and see for yourself.